# How can I intercept jdbc connection string from TCP connection in HAProxy

Tags: jdbc, tcp, haproxy

I need to find username or appinfo to decide which database server to forward the request to in HAProxy.
I tried this in config:

```
tcp-request inspect delay 1s
tcp-request content capture req.payload(0,0) len 1480
log-format %[capture.req.hdr(0)]
tcp-request content accept if WAIT_END
```

But the payload logged is unreadable/junk values. I tried writing acl apart from logging but it also doesnot work.

Database is sybase IQ and driver SQLAnywhere to connect. This is being done in tcp mode.

What is the right way to do this in HAProxy?

Comment: There is no 'connection string' in a TCP connect request. Are you talking about HTTP?

Comment: No i m creating a jdbc connection to my database(which is tcp). How does the database get all the connection details if it is not passed on to it in tcp payload?( The jdbc connection string eg. jdbc:sqlanywhere:UID=saloni;PWD=xyz;LINKS=TCPIP{host=xyz:1350} must be somewhere in the connection request right?)